# Cannot click the ShareActionProvider in Action Bar?

Tags: android

I am using the following code on a API 15 (Galaxy Nexus) avdevice

The menu_share.xml

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:orderInCategory="20"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="Refresh">
</item>
```

The main activity looks like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    // Get the ActionProvider
    provider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share)
        .getActionProvider();
    // Initialize the share intent
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    provider.setShareIntent(intent);
    return true;
}
```

When I run it on a API 15 (Galaxy Nexus) avd it shows me only the following icon that I cannot click (although it should show me at least the messageing app).

[image: API15]

When I run the same code on a API 17 tablet avd I can start the Messaging app offered by the SharedActionProvider - it looks like this

[image]

On the tablet how can I make the Messageing app to show in the dropdown list instead like this and how to make the shared action provider on the API15 AVD clickable (first image)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known Android bug. Check related [bug report](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/415) in ActionBarSherlock and android [bug itself](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25467). 
Bug is 1.5 years old and still not fixed.